# Concatenate string to the end of all elements of a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, string-concatenation

I would like to know how to concatenate a string to the end of all elements in a list.

**For example:**

```
List1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
string = "a"

output = ['1a' , '2a' , '3a']
```

Comment: `output = ["".join([string,str(i)]) for i in List1]`

Comment: @VasilisG. your answer inserts the string into new elements in the list, it's not good. I just want to concatenate the string to the end of the existing elements of the list.

Comment: @Markus84612 you have a point there, you can just flip `string` and `str(i)` positions in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rebuild the list in a list comprehension and use `str.format` on both parameters

```
>>> string="a"
>>> List1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
>>> output = ["{}{}".format(i,string) for i in List1]
>>> output
['1a', '2a', '3a']
```

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
>>> lst = [1 , 2 , 3]
>>> my_string = 'a'
>>> [str(x) + my_string for x in lst]
['1a', '2a', '3a']
```

You need to convert the integer into strings and create a new strings for each element. A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works well for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
s = "a"
print map(lambda x: str(x)+s, L);
```

**output**
['1a', '2a', '3a']

Comment: this is python 2 only, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
List1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
string = "a"
new_list = list(map(lambda x:"{}{}".format(x, string), List1))
```

Output:

```
['1a', '2a', '3a']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = map(lambda x:str(x)+'a',List1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
str1="a"
new_list = []
for item in List1:
    new_list.append(str(item)+str1)
print(new_list)
```

Convert each element in the list to string and then add the required string to each element of the list.

Comment: OP wants a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> List1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
>>> string = "a"
>>> output = [s + string for s in map(str, List1)]
>>> output
['1a', '2a', '3a']
```

Answer (score -1):

A 1 liner:

```
List1= [s + a for s in List1]
```