# Concatenate strings from the cartesian product of two list (preferably without for loop)

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, list-comprehension

Using a for loop to iterate and concatenate words to create several permutations. My for loop works but I'd rather not use a for loop as I want to have the code on one line so I can create a variable.

What options do I have? Basic question I realize.

Here's the two lists I want to concatenate:

```
first = ["Happy", "Sad", "Fun"]
second = ["Game", "Movie"]
```

desired output:

```
combo = ["Happy Game", "Happy Movie", "Sad Game", "Sad Movie", "Fun Game", "Fun Movie"]
```

This for loop works but I want it on one line and as a variable:

```
for b in first:
    for s in second:
        combo = b + ' ' + s
        print(combo)
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: `[b + ' ' + s for b in first for s in second]`. Why is this tagged pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: A for loop is probably the most straightforward way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243018/concatenate-string-to-the-end-of-all-elements-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()`, `map()` and `str.join` to achieve this result without using `for` loop (not even within *list comprehension*) as:

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> first = ["Happy", "Sad", "Fun"]
>>> second = ["Game", "Movie"]

>>> map(' '.join, product(first, second))
['Happy Game', 'Happy Movie', 'Sad Game', 'Sad Movie', 'Fun Game', 'Fun Movie']
```

Here *`itertools.product()`* returns the cartesian product of your iterables.

Refer below documents for more details:

- [`itertools.product()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
- [`map()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`str.join()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a list comprehension is the way to do this in a one-liner:

```py
combos = [b + ' ' + s for b in first for s in second]
```

This basically ends up doing the same as this:

```py
combos = []

for b in first:
    for s in second:
        combos.append(b + ' ' + s)
```

The result:

```
>>> combos
['Happy Game', 'Happy Movie', 'Sad Game', 'Sad Movie', 'Fun Game', 'Fun Movie']
```

See here for more information on list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: but list comprehension also contains for loop (if that counts)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri That's true I suppose, although I believe OP's main request was for a one-liner that assigns to a variable, so either solution should work fine. There's more than one way to do this I guess. ‍♂️ Great answer though!