# Concatenate each string element of one list to all elements of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

```
year = ['2019', '2020', '2021', '2022']
week = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1,53)]
```

I'm trying to join/concatenate each string element of year list to all elements of week list as follows

```
['201901'
'201902'
'201903'
.
.
.
.
.
'202250'
'202251'
'202252']
```

- Output should be a list

I can achieve this using following code

```
week = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1,53)]
year = [str(i) for i in range(2019,2023)]*len(range(2019,2023))*52
year.sort()
print({i:year.count(i) for i in year})

li = []
for yr in set(year):
    li.append([i + j for i, j in zip([k for k in year if yr in k], week)])
yr_week_id = sorted(list(np.concatenate(li)))
print(yr_week_id)
```

**Is there any simpler solution to this problem?**

Comment: `[year + weak for year in map(str, range(2019, 2023)) for weak in map('{0:>02}'.format, range(1, 53))]` or `[f'{year}{weak:>02}' for year in range(2019, 2023) for weak in range(1, 53)]`

Comment: Similar: `[str(year) + str(weak).rjust(2,'0') for year in range(2019, 2023) for weak in range(1, 53)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings from the cartesian product of two list (preferably without for loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484461/concatenate-strings-from-the-cartesian-product-of-two-list-preferably-without-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the *week* list. You can just calculate the week numbers as you go along.

You may not even need the *year* list if the range of years can be expressed with *range()*

```
year = ['2019', '2020', '2021', '2022']
output = []
for yy in year:
    output.extend([f'{yy}{ww:02d}' for ww in range(1, 53)])
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['201901',
'201902',
...
'202251',
'202252']
```

Comment: Output should be a list. Thanks!!

Comment: @Suhas_Pote You edited your question **after** I posted this answer. You really should be clear with your question. Anyway... code changed accordingly

Comment: Apologies, I'll ensure all the details in question before posting it.